# Can Windows 2012 R2 act as an VPN client using IKEv1?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to find out if 2012 R2 can connect to a VPN with the following data:

1. Phase 1 Proposal: pre-g20-aes256-sha2-256 (86400)
2. Phase 2 Proposal: esp-g20-aes256-sha2-256 (4800)
3. IKEv1
4. PFS enabled
5. pre-shared keys

Is that possible? For example, I don't find IKEv1 as an option, only IKEv2, PPTP, L2TP/IPSec, and SSTP.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only use IKEv2 or L2TP/IPSEC.  Here is a guide on how to setup L2TP/IPSEC.

https://www.magnumvpn.com/setup-vpn-windows-10-l2tp-ipsec.html

You might also need to open your windows firewall for it to work.

https://www.magnumvpn.com/setup-windows-10-firewall-l2tp.html

Comment: Do you have any Microsoft reference or such to support your statement that IKEv1 is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but as a workaround, you can install [VyOS](https://vyos.io/) on a virtual machine.

Either on that Windows machine in question itself, or somewhere else. I just did that, and VyOS works like a charm as my VPN router with the above parameters, and many more details like NATting etc that are easy to configure in VyOS. (But VPN site-to-site itself is not easy at all)

Comment: Yes but not in RRAS. It needs to be done using Windows Firewall